# PHP replace space with - expect at the end

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have this code here:

```
$this->view->category_name = $categoryName;
$albumName = strtolower($categoryName);
$albumName = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $albumName);
```

and what this does it turn my string into lowercase and replace spaces with - ...however I have a category named "Miscellaneous" my code above turns into "miscellaneous" and then "miscellaneous-" how come its doing this and how can I adjust my code so it does not add it to the end?

Comment: what does `var_dump($categoryName);` give? I have the feeling that the problem is already in that string, so you probably need to fix this further up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the last dash. Finish off your code with:

```
$albumName = trim($albumName, '-');
```

Comment: My guess is the original string contains a space - so the trim could be done here `trim(strtolower($categoryName))` as well.